# Merging Mercurial conflicts in Netbeans

Tags: mercurial, netbeans

If you look in the image below..

The top left is my changes:

```
$static_pages = 'terms|privacy|about|home|media';
```

The top right is some one elses changes.

```
$static_pages = 'terms|privacy|about|home|history';
```

And the bottom is the result after merge.

[image]

It wants me to pick one and discard the other. The way it should actually be merged is:

```
$static_pages = 'terms|privacy|about|home|history|media';
```

However, there is no way (that I can tell) for me to select that.

I tried to select one of the two, then make the appropriate changes in the bottom window, but it would not let me make any edits.

I had to select one, save it, then reopen the file and add the rest and save again. This doesn't seem right. Am I doing something wrong or is that just the way it is?

Comment: Well, it is possible to do this using Mercurial ([here's](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UZEim.png) a screenshot of me doing what you intended ('cept I missed the ending `';`, but that's a typo), just using the default tools provided with TortoiseHg), so it's possibly a gap in the implementation of Netbeans? I don't use it to be of any more help though I'm afraid...

Comment: @DMA57361 I think maybe I will use the KDiff3 app in your screenshot specifically for merging then. Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend selecting Martin as the answer.  Good to know this is a feature lacking in Netbeans

Comment: @Webnet I agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be the way it is: the [Mercurial guide](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mercurial.html#merging) has a dead link to `#resolving` anchor that doesn't exist! :-) In the corresponding [Subversion guide](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html#resolving), the anchor is there, but they only say that you can select the version you want.

It has been asked [before on the NetBeans Forums](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-62602.html) and the reply was that it's a known limitation and that you'll have to hand-edit the file afterwards. Luckily `hg merge` and `hg commit` are separate commands in Mercurial, so you have the opportunity to fix the conflict before committing.

However, since it can be impossible to remember all the files that need editing, I strongly agree with DMA5761 when he suggest using a more capable three-way merge tool, such as the KDiff3 that comes with TortoiseHg.